# LOADING SPACY INTO ANACONDA

Tags: python, text, nlp, jupyter, spacy

I use jupyter notebook and python3 version.I tried several ways of installing spacy and the lastest I tried is given as follows

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

I got this error message. Can someone help me identify the problem.

```
[E053] Could not read config.cfg from C:\Users\aabbcc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.2.0\config.cfg
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated to python 3.7 and that worked.